# Insert null values to small arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [xx] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 15
            [6] => 49
            [7] => 14
            [8] => 7
            [9] => 2
            [10] => 3
        )

    [yy] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
        )

)
```

I want to insert null values to yy array  by comparing with xx array means by comparing with larger array i need to insert null values to smaller arrays in their indexes . finally i need output like

```
Array
(
    [xx] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 15
            [6] => 49
            [7] => 14
            [8] => 7
            [9] => 2
            [10] => 3
        )

    [yy] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
            [4] => null
            [5] => null
            [6] => null
            [7] => null
            [8] => null
            [9] => null
            [10] => null
        )

)
```

not only xx and yy . array may extend .we have to compare each and every array and insert nulls in smaller arrays and match with the size of larger array . finally every array count should be same

Comment: I've literally understood nothing of what you want to do. How do you need to compare them? what's the input you have and the output you expect?

Comment: have u tried any code till now?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) If you don't post any code or haven't tried to find the solution by yourself, you probably should not have asked this.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to *pad* the yy array to the same size of xx:

```
$array['yy'] = array_pad($array['yy'], count($array['xx']), null);
```

To equalise a whole lot of arrays:

```
$length = max(array_map('count', $array));
$array = array_map(
    function (array $a) use ($length) { return array_pad($a, $length, null); },
    $array
);
```

Comment: I think he wants it to go both ways.

Comment: Then I'll leave it up to him to do the same thing again, reversing xx and yy.

Comment: He probably wants to pad to the larger array, but it's not hard to do and can be found very easily

Comment: not only xx and yy . array may extend .we have to compare each and every array and insert nulls in smaller arrays and match with the size of larger array . finally every array count should be same

Comment: @Saranvarma How about you clarify that in the question from the start? Anyway, see update.

Comment: its not xx and yy array may it extends to zz or dd or anything so many arrays are there i want to match all arrays count in that particular parent array with nulls in empty indexes

Comment: @Saranvarma Yes, I got that. Have you seen my update?

Comment: sorry bro not working.$chart is main array which contains xx,yy arrays i mean all sub arrays . can you please explain

Comment: @Saranvarma I don't get what you're not getting: http://3v4l.org/TKFGB#v540. Works fine.

Comment: Array
(
    [Dow Jones] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 15
            [6] => 49
            [7] => 14
            [8] => 7
            [9] => 2
            [10] => 3
        )

    [Direct US] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
        )

)    my array is like this

Comment: @Saranvarma And what is the problem with that? Works fine: http://3v4l.org/QvSfJ#v530

Comment: Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array if i pass $chart array to this

Comment: sorry bro its working fine now. Thank you .its totally my mistake